# Customizing Single Sign on in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I have multiple client and use IdentityServer4 for authentication.    After I am logged into the first client the subsequent client are automatically logged in due to single Sign On.   However what I want to know is,  does the second client's authentication request makes any round trip to IdentityServer.    If yes is there a way to intercept this call either by extending or customizing the implementation.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to intercept it?

Comment: I want to take some action like redirecting the user to a custom endpoint if the user is signing in for the first time from this client.    With Single Sign On I will not be able to do this unless I intercept.

Comment: You could just require a consent for the new clients, this will automatically run the consent flow. Here, you can do anything you like. Otherwise, take a look at overriding some methods from ```AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator```

Comment: I tried this by add a custom AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator  but it never gets called for the subsequent application.  However this helped in other things though

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the clients where you want to intercept use the implicit or hybrid flow.

If so, have you tried one of the events on OpenIdConnectEvents? Say OnTokenValidated?

[OpenIdConnectEvents Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: The OpenIdConnectEvent I guess is on the client application side, I want this to be on the server side